# Custom checked radio buttons that persist an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

In a page I have a list of radio buttons, each of them enclosed it's own form, and on-click the form is submitted through an AJAX call, saves the user's selection, and refreshes that list.

I want to customize the checked radio buttons by replacing the form around them and it's contents with an img of a check-mark so, using **jQuery** I do:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $("input:checked").parent().html('<img alt="Checked" src="/img/tick.png"/>');
});
```

My problem is that as soon as I'm selecting a different radio button, I'm making an AJAX call that saves my option and refreshes the div with all my radio buttons.

I tried to use [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but I was unsuccessful; no `change` event (maybe my approach wasn't good?)

Is there a way I could make the changes persist an AJAX refresh? Or what would an alternative approach be?

Comment: Please give us more codes so we can play around. Post codes to JSfiddle if possible. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to move the line of code you have from the docuemnt.ready into a method.  On ajax success, call that method.

You will still want to call the method in the document.ready so the initial load is done correctly.